# How delete users from table when they aren't in page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I want to make if user is on page `localhost/chat` add him to table `users_chat` but when he is on other page for example `localhost/faq` delete him from `users_chat` table.

I have this code but it wont work:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); 
if($url === 'localhost/czat'){     
      $uzytkownicy_on = $db->query('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO chat_users(id, login, activity) VALUES (:id, :login, :activity)', array(
            ':id' => $_SESSION['userid'],
            ':login' => $_SESSION['username'],
            ':activity' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))              
        ));
}else{
    $uzytkownicy_on = $db->query('DELETE FROM chat_users WHERE id = :id', array(
            ':id' => $_SESSION['userid'];
        ));
}
```

Comment: you can design it this way, every time a user clicks back for example, from his/her session id have them deleted from the table. I am not sure how it works when a user opens a new tab, did you consider it?

Comment: I really dont know. I want to add users online on chat without refreshing page.

Comment: you can't think of it this way. Every time a new user enters the page, they are being inserted to the table in the db. Every time they leave, you delete them.

Comment: But how I can do it. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: I have never did it. I am sure you can find tutorials online.

Comment: Can you explain me what i have to search for?